# echo server not writing back to client

Tags: c, networking, server, client

I'm building a client server program

the server is a shell and requires the user to login first

from debugging I have discovered that my `Rio_write()` command is executing, but my `Rio_readlineb()` command (on the client side) is not catching what the server is writing to it

on the client side I have...

```
  printf("Username: ");
  Fgets(username, 128, stdin);
  strtok(username, "\n"); //splice newline off
  strcat(username, " "); //concatenate a space
  printf("Password: ");
  Fgets(password, 128, stdin);
  strcat(username, password);
  Rio_writen(clientfd, username, strlen(username));
  Rio_readlineb(&rio, buf, MAXLINE);
```

and debugging, it gets stuck on the last line

on the server side I have

```
  Rio_readinitb(&rio, connfd);
  Rio_readlineb(&rio, buf, MAXLINE);
  //scan through user text file and verify user and password exists
  file = Fopen("rrshusers.txt", "r");
  while (Fgets(login, MAXLINE, file) != NULL){
    if (!strcmp(buf, login)){ //case where the username and password is verified
      flag = 1;
      strcpy(buf, "Login Approved");
      Rio_writen(connfd, buf, strlen(buf));
      break;
    }
  }
```

like I said, from debugging I can see that the write function is executed, and the program moves on, but the client never reads

what's weird is that, it successfully reads if I terminate my server with Ctrl-C

Comment: Are you writing a line?

Comment: I'm writing `buf` back to the client

Comment: Hmm.. you may have to resort to wireshark to ensure that what is being sent is what Rio_readlineb() expects.

Comment: please upvote for visibility

Comment: You're writing `buf` back to the client but you're not writing a *line*.

Comment: so does it need to be followed by \n?

Comment: Mebbe it's an CR/LF/CRLF thing?

Comment: @kendall - why ask us?  You have the code for the Rio_XXX thingies.  Put an extra \n in and see what happens.

Comment: lol sorry I would've but I was afk, but that actually worked! thanks